# JavaScript Function Reference

Tags: javascript

Consider this code, which sets `a` to a function. Then `f` points to `a`, but then `a` gets set to `null`.

```
var a = function () { 
    return 5;
};

var f = a; 

a = null;
```

However, when calling `f()`, `5` prints out.

```
console.log(f());
```

> 5

Why doesn't calling `f()` result in a null object reference?

http://jsfiddle.net/deDca/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's step by step what is happening:

```
var a = function () { 
    return 5;
};
```

Assigns a function reference to the variable `a`.

---

```
var f = a;
```

Assigns the same function reference to the variable `f`.  At this point, both `a` and `f` contain a reference to the same function.

---

```
a = null;
```

Clears `a` so it no longer contains that function reference.  But, `f` still contains the function reference and has nothing to do with `a` so you can change the value of `a` to your heart's content and it will not affect what `f` has.  After the second step above, each variable had it's own unique reference to the function.  `a` and `f` did not point at each other.

It's like if you have two friends and you tell each of them a secret password.  Now, you tell the first friend that the password is now different.  The second friend still has the original password - they are not affected by the fact that you told the first friend something different.

Answer (score 1):

I'll preface my answer by saying that functions are objects in javascript, so we're really talking about object references in general.

You can't actually `null` the object in memory. You're only setting a reference to the actual object to `null`. `f` is a reference to that object, just like `a` is. You're making `a` no longer a reference to that object, but that doesn't affect `f` at all.

The garbage collector will take care of actually removing the object altogether.

In case that's unclear, I'll explain in other words:

`var a = {};` makes an object in memory. `a` isn't actually that object, but a reference to it.

`var f = a` means that `f` now references the same object that `a` references.

`a = null;` means that `a` no longer references the object, but doesn't affect the object itself. `f` still references that object.

Answer (score 0):

(In JavaScript) A variable is like a box that can contain something (`var a = ...;`). Two boxes can contain the same thing (`var f = a;`). If you put something else into one of the boxes (`a = null`), it doesn't change the content of the other box (`f`), even if it originally contained the same thing.